# AngularDart NgComponent using event listeners in the controller

Tags: dart, shadow-dom, angular-dart

I have an `NgComponent` in Angular Dart which instantiates a search box and according to the query strings it populates another div in my html template with the `ng-repeat` directive.

More precisely,

Query string update: there is a binding to the input text value with a field in my components' controller.

Results population: In the `attach()` method I added a watcher for the local field which acts as a model to the input box, and whenever it changes I add to a local list some items which then acts as a model to the `ng-repeat` directive in another div.

So far everything works fine. But now I want to add some event listeners inside my component, like keystroke listeners or if possible to add listeners on specific elements in my html template. I have used CSS for hover and focus events and also `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` for easy functions. But I do not think that this can be used for keystroke listeners.

The reason I want the keystroke listener is to enable results traversing using the arrow keys. While the cursor is inside the input text box I would like to move to the first result, which is in another div, with the press of Down arrow, and then continue to the other results.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, It seems that I have finally found the solution.

The solution is to implement the `NgShadowRootAware` interface with my component and then inside the void `onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot)` method I have full access to the DOM created inside the shadow dom template.