# NgComponent ready event

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to create a `NgComponent` which is populated with elements when the component is loaded. How do I know when the component is populated with the template? Here is some of my code:

```dart
class SleepTimeModule extends Module {
  SleepTimeModule() {
    //...
    type(SleepGraph);
    //...
  }
}

//...

@NgComponent(
  selector: 'sleep-graph',
  publishAs: 'sleepGraph',
  template: '<div><svg></svg></div>'
)
class SleepGraph {
  Element element;
  Scope scope;

  @NgTwoWay('data')
  var data;

  SleepGraph(this.element, this.scope);

  // when can I call this method?
  // it modifies the dom
  drawChart(data){
    js.context.callMethod("drawChart", [
      element.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg"),
      new js.JsObject.jsify(data)
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `NgShadowRootAware`'s `onShadowRoot` method, like this:

```
//...
class SleepGraph implements NgShadowRootAware {
    //...
    // This method is called when the dom is ready
    void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot){

    }
}
```

There are already similar questions:

- [AngularDart NgComponent using event listeners in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820745/angulardart-ngcomponent-using-event-listeners-in-the-controller/20820828#20820828)
- [How to add a component programatically in Angular.Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565/how-to-add-a-component-programatically-in-angular-dart/20434382#20434382)